Definition of a subsequences and intuition
This question hopes to better understand the ideas of subsequences between the formal and informal ideas regarding this.
P.S I am new to StackExchange, so my notation is a little funny (suggestions appreciated on this also).
The definition of a subsequence according to my lecture notes is defined as follows:
A subsequence of (an) is a new sequence bi = an(i) for all i in N where n(1) < n(2) < n(3) < ... < n(i) < ... for all i.
So with this formal definition.
Let's consider the following sequence (an). (an) := (1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,...), can I pick a subsequence such as (1,3,4,2,3,1,2,...)?
i.e a subsequence with no apparent function from i to n(i), random as long as n(1) < n(2) < n(3) < ... < n(i) < ... for all i is still satisfied.

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

Yup.  Imagine you have a sequence and two friends.  And you just start reading the terms of the sequence out in order.  Friend 1 arbitrarily for no reason whatsoever will say yes or no after you read each number.  Which one he says yes to and which he says no to are utterly random.  Friend 2 just writes down the terms friend 1 says yes to.  Friend 2 has written down a sequence and the sequence she wrote is a completely acceptable subsequence.  Really, a subsequence is a concept that is so simple it's dang near impossible to define without sounding really complicated.

Short answer: yes. There is no need for the function that selects the subsequence to have a formula.
